# Setting all the text-inputs on the page to one value

Tags: javascript

Example html:

```
<input type="text" name="nhdd9812"></input>
<input type="text" name="ndf4e"></input>
<input type="text" name="018y3"></input>
<input type="text" name="nsiohf8"></input>
```

How can I by javascript, set all text-inputs on the page to one value? (Without knowing their ids/names). Lets say "1" for examples sake.

Is this possible without a framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input:text");
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) { inputs[i].value = 1; }
```

Comment: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': 'input:text' is not a valid selector.